# Dart/Flutter async-await skips method and continues with the rest of the code

Tags: flutter, dart

Async-await skips method and continues with the rest of the code, which results in an error code because my variable is not assigned with the value result of my method.

I have been trying multiple methods to accomplish my goal but without success. I have tried converting every ".then" into "Async-Await", make my void method a "Future" method, invoke method within InitState. Futurebuilder wouldnt be a solution as I am not trying to build anything with it.

The code seems to skip after
"await _firestore.collection('auth_user').doc(userid).get();" it goes out and continues at the Widget build. Therefore companyid seems to be null as its not finished yet.

My Screen

```
class Chatroom extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chatroom({super.key});

  @override
  _ChatroomState createState() => _ChatroomState();
}

class _ChatroomState extends State<Chatroom> {
  final userservice = UserService();
  final chatservice = ChatService();
  String? companyid = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser();
  }

  Future<void> getUser() async {
    try {
      final cpid = await userservice.getCompanyId();
      setState(() {
        companyid = cpid;
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("test"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Expanded(child: _buildUserList()),
      ]),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatservice.getChats(companyid ?? ''),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('error');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text('loading..');
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((document) => _userCard(document))
              .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _userCard(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Column(children: [
      Text(data['name'] ?? 'Anonymous:${doc.id}'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Service where I use method from

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future<String> getCompanyId() async {
    try {
      String userid = _firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;
      DocumentSnapshot doc =
          await _firestore.collection('auth_user').doc(userid).get();

      final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      String companyid = data['companyId'];

      return companyid;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.code);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.code);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The widget is always going to build as soon as its added to the widget tree.

You can solve this by adding a loading state and showing a CircularProgressIndicator while it is true:

```
// In your state

bool loading = true;

// Update loading after the user is loaded
Future<void> getUser() async {
    try {
      final cpid = await userservice.getCompanyId();
      setState(() {
        companyid = cpid;
        loading = false; // Here
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

In your widget, just check for this loading flag and only render the full widget when it's false.

Comment: Man you just learned me some, wasted hours for such small thing XD. Thank you :)